# Motor para crear formularios con campos dinámicos en Vue JS. ¿Usar HTML Template o Vue Render?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, formularios

buenas noches comunidad!

Estoy tratando de crear un motor para construir formularios con campos dinámicos a partir de un esquema en JSON, el cuál recibiré del backend mediante el consumo de un endpoint.

Actualmente tengo un componente principal, el cual le envia a un componente secundario un JSON con los controles que necesito renderizar.

**Componente principal**

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>{{msg}}</h1>
    <b-container>
      <b-card>
        <b-card-title>Formulario Dinámico</b-card-title>
        <b-card-body>
           <FormControls :fields="fields"></FormControls>
        </b-card-body>
        <b-card-footer>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="send">Enviar</button>
        </b-card-footer>
      </b-card>
    </b-container>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import FormControls from "./FormControls.vue";
import ComponentTest from "./ComponentTest.vue";
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    FormControls,
    ComponentTest
  },
  created() { 
    axios.get('./src/form.json').then(response => this.fields = response.data); 
  },
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Bienvenido',
      fields: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    send: () => {
      // Código para procesar el formulario sin conocer los controles
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

**Componente Secundario**

```js
<template>
  <div>
  <form>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="field in fields" :key="field">
        <label :for="field.name">{{field.label}}</label>

        <input v-if="isInput(field.type)" 
        :id="field.name" :type="field.type" :placeholder="field.placeholder" >

        <select v-else-if="field.type === 'select'" :name="field.name">
          <option v-for="opt in field.options" :key="opt" :value="opt.name">
          {{opt.label}}
          </option>
        </select>

        <textarea v-else-if="field.type === 'textarea'" :id="field.name" />
        
        <div v-else-if="field.type === 'multiselect'" class="multi-select">
          <multiselect v-model="values" tag-placeholder="Agregar etiqueta" :placeholder="field.placeholder" label="label" track-by="name" :options="field.options" :multiple="true" :taggable="true" @tag="agregarEtiqueta"></multiselect>
        </div>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['fields'],
  name: 'FormControls',
  data () {
    return {
      titulo: 'Formulario Dinámico',
      // Aqui va lo del MultiSelect
      values: [],
      options: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    isInput(type) {
      return ['text', 'password', 'checkbox', 'file', 'date'].includes(type);
    },
    // Método multiselect
    agregarEtiqueta (newTag) {
      const tag = {
        name: newTag,
        label: newTag.substring(0, 2) + Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000000))
      }
      this.options.push(tag)
      this.value.push(tag)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Esquema Json que devolvería el Backend**

```js
[
    {
      "name": "fechaRegistro",
      "label": "Fecha de Registro",
      "type": "date",
      "placeholder": "Ingresa Fecha"
    },
    {
      "name": "nombreDeUsuario",
      "label": "Nombre de Usuario",
      "type": "text",
      "placeholder": "Ingresa Usuario"
    },
    {
      "name": "passwordUsuario",
      "label": "Password",
      "type": "password",
      "placeholder": "Contraseña"
    },
    {
      "name": "adjuntarArchivo",
      "label": "Adjuntar",
      "type": "file"
    },
    {
      "name": "roles",
      "label": "Roles",
      "type": "select",
      "sortedByKey": false,
      "options": [{
          "name": "admin",
          "label": "Administrador"
        },
        {
          "name": "user",
          "label": "Usuario"
        },
        {
          "name": "guest",
          "label": "Invitado"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "description",
      "label": "Descripción",
      "type": "textarea"
    },
    {
      "name": "multiSelect",
      "label": "Selección Multiple",
      "type": "multiselect",
      "options": [{
          "name": "op1",
          "label": "Opcion1"
        },
        {
          "name": "op2",
          "label": "Opcion2"
        },
        {
          "name": "op3",
          "label": "Opcion3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Hasta aquí todo funciona bien, pues renderiza los controles de entrada correctamente de acuerdo al esquema JSON que obtengo. Sin embargo pensando en como manejar los eventos de cada control y recuperar sus datos de forma dinámica me surge la duda de si seguir utilizando HTML Templates o bien optar por Vue Render y controlar las cosas desde JavaScript.

Además me gustaría leer sus respuestas con ideas de cómo estructurar mis componentes y código, de tal manera que sea lo más dinámico y reciclable posible para crear nuevos formularios a partir de un json.

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Tienes dos maneras de recoger los datos del componente hijo:

- Hacer referencia a tu componente con **$refs**. En tu caso sería así `<FormControls :fields="fields" ref="formcontrol"></FormControls>`. En tu componente padre puedes encontrar todo lo que contiene FormControls con this.$refs.formcontrol.
- En segundo lugar, quizás te sea mas sencillo generar componentes dinamicos, es decir, creas tantos componentes como campos vayas a usar en tu form (textarea,input,select...) y luegos los randerizas de manera dinamica asi:

  > ```
  > <div v-for="v-for="field in fields"">
  >
  > <component v-bind:is="field.type">
  >
  > </component></div>
  > ```

Si en este segundo caso, incluyes referencias a los componentes, podrás obtener también todo lo relativo a lo que contienen. Una manera fácil de obtener los v-model de todos esos componentes es incluir una función en cada componente hijo que retorne el valor de los v-model, y ejecutar dicha llamda en el padre a través de los $refs. Ejemplo: `this.$refs.inputField.retornoValores` Esto tantas veces como te componentes tenga tu llamada, por lo que lo suyo es hacer un for de $refs, ya que normalmente las referencias son un array de objetos.